# Ms Excel VBA - How to select cells till the end of column, copy and paste it to different worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've 3 Sheets in a Workbook.

Sheet 1 - The source data
Sheet 2 & 3 - I wanted to paste data from `Sheet 1` here at `A1` till the end of the column depending the size of data in `Sheet 1`.

The following VBA script copy the content of current worksheet (Sheet 1) till the end of the column, and paste it to `Sheet 2` and `Sheet 3`.

```
Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Paste
Worksheets("Sheet 3").Paste
```

The problem is the copied content will be paste to the location of selected cells which is random cells depending where it was pointed.

I wanted it to be copied at specific location which is `A1` till the end of the column on the other sheets.

So I changed the syntax. Unfortunately the following attempts didn't work and caused error.

```
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").Paste
```

The error is:

```
Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

What is the right syntax for this?

**Update**

I've changed the last code as suggested but it just selected `A1:XFD1` in `Sheet 2`. It did not copy the content from `Sheet 1`

```
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: `.Paste` is not a method of `Range`, hence the error. Try `.PasteSpecial` instead, see if you can use that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Macro to copy as values distinct values from one Excel tab to another](https://superuser.com/questions/1494777/macro-to-copy-as-values-distinct-values-from-one-excel-tab-to-another) or https://superuser.com/questions/884115/macro-to-copy-distinct-values-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another or https://superuser.com/questions/548922/excel-2010-macro-copy-cell-range-with-formulas-and-paste-values-only or https://superuser.com/questions/1466255/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-to-different-workbook-at-end-of-existing-data

Comment: This is probably the single most asked VBA question on this stack, to say nothing of how many times this must have been covered on SO

Comment: Thanks @ChristoferWeber, however it didn't work. `.PasteSpecial` just highighted the second sheet, that's it. It didn't paste the content from the first sheet.

Also, how to find out which method is working for `Range` and which one is not?

I'm new to this and just try and error based on code on the internet. Your help would be highly appreciated. 

+1 for you for helping.

Comment: @AlexM, frankly speaking, I don't understand at all the link you sent. Doesn't seems related to my case. Please take note that I'm very new to VBA and just want to make it done. That's it.

Comment: If you write `Range.`  the editor should give you a list of things available. If not, you should be able to right click and open the "list of  properties and methods". Apart from that, I usually refer to the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial

Comment: As for why it doesn't work, not sure. Your copy and (edited) paste code seem to work for me. If you look at the documentation for `Range.Copy`, you will see that you can paste with it as well, by adding `Destination:=` at the end. You could try that.

Comment: @user11392987 I understand that you're new; Super User is not a script writing service. You're expected to make an effort to research the fundamental elements of the answer you need. You don't seem to have done much reading on this subject so I gave you a few places to start.

Answer (score -1):

I quote from your question:

> copied content will be pasted to the location of selected cells

this is true.

> which is random cells depending where it was pointed

this doesn't have to be.

Just put `worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").Select` before the paste lines. EDIT - you might have to do it in two parts, `worksheets("worksheet name").Select` then `Range("A1").select`.